# Is a blackhole just a neutrino with much more mass?

Tags: black-holes, mass, neutrinos, point-particles

If there was a blackhole that had a mass similar to that of a neutrino ($0.320 ± 0.081\,\mathrm{eV/c^2}$), would we still be able to differentiate the blackhole from the neutrino?  Is there any property that a blackhole has that is different from a neutrino other than mass?

Comment: Did you read up on what black holes are and what makes a neutrino a neutrino?

Comment: Yes I have.  My point is that they are both point particles with no charge.

Comment: Neither a neutrino nor a black hole are point particles. There are no point particles. A neutrino is an excitation of a quantum field with lepton number +/-1, spin 1/2, no charge etc.. It oscillates into other types of neutrinos. Black holes don't do the latter, for sure.

Comment: So how would a black hole behave once it has evaporated to the mass of a neutrino?

Comment: A black hole will not evaporate to a neutrino in its center of mass coordinate system.

Comment: Is it fair to say that we can't be certain how a black hole will behave once it has evaporated to the mass of a neutrino?

Comment: Why will a black hole not evaporate to a neutrino in its center of mass coordinate system?

Comment: It is fair to say that we can say that a black hole will not evaporate into a single neutrino. It will evaporate into a great number of charged and uncharged particles, some of them neutrinos, but you would not be able to say "that one" was the last remnant of the black hole.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets take this a step at a time.

A [black hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole) is an object posited by the classical theory of [General relativity.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity) It is a legitimate solution for the case of a great accretion of mass which has a singularity at the origin, and it has a definition of a radius called an event horizon which once any mass goes through it cannot come out because of the great attraction of this singularity.

A neutrino is an elementary particle studied in elementary particle interactions and is a **quantum mechanical entity**. [In the standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) of particle physics it is a point particle and has a very small mass.

General Relativity is not quantized in a consistent manner to the inclusion of the standard model of physics , although string theories are on the way of defining a definite model.

Therefore it is not consistent to talk of black holes and neutrinos in a same model until the research has reached a phase where there exists a standard model for quantization of general relavity.

The [Schwartzschild radius](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/astro/blkhol.html) of a black hole horizon, for example , calculated for a one kilogram mass

[image: event horizon]

is 1.4837554589428308x10^-27 meters. Considering that the dimensions of a proton are one fermi , 10^-15 meters , a black hole with the mass of one kilogram, a classical weight, would be much smaller than the quantum mechanical dimensions of elementary particles, which become evident at 10^-9  meters. Thus it has no meaning to mix black holes and their classical behavior with elementary particles until a consistent theoretical model is found.

Comment: The Schawrzschild radius for Earth mass is much bigger than that, about 1cm.

Comment: @MBN I got the number from the link in Hyperphysics, you may be right if I made a mistake in using the automatic calculation

Comment: @MBN  OK, I misread  the labels. it is .887x10^-2meters. The number I posted is for one kilogram. I will edit. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The neutrino is a weakly interacting particle, thus it has some quantum numbers ([weak isospin, hypercharge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_interaction#Weak_isospin_and_weak_hypercharge)) which is summed to zero in the black hole. Thus, even if we don't take in sight the numerous related problems (see Annas answer above), the answer is *no*.